# Where can I read "How abstract is phonology?"?

Tags: phonology, reference-request, spe

Where can I find a copy of Paul Kiparsky's *How abstract is phonology?* written in 1968?

The only place version I've found so far is a [snippet view on Google Books](http://books.google.co.uk/books/about/How_abstract_is_phonology.html?id=mQRZAAAAMAAJ&redir_esc=y) and [this summary](http://anthropology.uwo.ca/faculty/creider/247/abstract.pdf).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I haven't found any online/digital versions, but I [came upon](http://books.google.nl/books?id=Q5x17Vm22rEC&pg=PA272) the places where it's reprinted. You should be able to get it in your library or via interlibrary loan, I suppose:

- Kiparsky, Paul. 1968. [How Abstract Is Phonology?](http://www.worldcat.org/oclc/2215592) Bloomington, Indiana: Indiana University Linguistics Club.
- Reprinted as a section (pp. 5-56) of: Kiparsky, Paul. 1973. “Phonological Representations.” In: [Three Dimensions of Linguistic Theory](http://www.worldcat.org/oclc/499860155), edited by Osamu Fujimura, Donald L Smith, S. I Harada, and Julie. B Lovins. Tokyo: Tokyo Institute for Advanced Studies of Language.
- Kiparsky, Paul. 1982. [Explanation in Phonology](http://www.worldcat.org/oclc/564487076). Dordrecht: Foris. Pp. 119-163.